# Incompatible return value type of python generic property usage that returns self

Tags: python, mypy

Trying to implement nodes and trees inheritance hierarchy that respects `mypy`, I have next classes:

```
from __future__ import annotations
import dataclasses
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Optional

GenericNodeValue = TypeVar('GenericNodeValue')

@dataclasses.dataclass
class BaseNode(Generic[GenericNodeValue]):
    value: GenericNodeValue
    parent: Optional[BaseNode] = None
    left: Optional[BaseNode] = None
    right: Optional[BaseNode] = None

    @property
    def dummy(self) -> BaseNode:
        return self

GenericNode = TypeVar('GenericNode', bound=BaseNode)

class BaseTree(Generic[GenericNode]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root: Optional[GenericNode] = None

    def get_dummy(self, node: GenericNode) -> GenericNode:
        return node.dummy

@dataclasses.dataclass
class RedBlackTreeNode(BaseNode[int]):
    red: bool = False

class RedBlackTree(BaseTree[RedBlackTreeNode]):
    def get_dummy2(self, node: RedBlackTreeNode) -> RedBlackTreeNode:
        return node.dummy
```

But `mypy` returns error:

```
test.py:29: error: Incompatible return value type (got "BaseNode[Any]", expected "GenericNode")
test.py:39: error: Incompatible return value type (got "BaseNode[Any]", expected "RedBlackTreeNode")
```

Is there any way I can implement my logic using python typing?

Comment: This is hard to model because the bounds of `TypeVar`s cannot be parameterized. You're left with `BaseNode[Any]` being the bound of `GenericNode`, instead of `BaseNode[GenericNodeValue]`.

Comment: But the design seems flawed in the first place. Why do you have a class representing a tree in addition to one for a node? A tree *is* a node with a filled `left` and `right`, and often no distinction is made between them. Removing that distinction you make would simplify the problem.

Comment: I agree in case of usage same node class issue will gone, but just example, different nodes can have different arguments: `class RedBlackTreeNode: red: bool` and `class AVLTreeNode: height: int`, without appropriate fields it can be tricky to implement appropriate `RedBlackTree` and  `AVLTree` that use this fields.

Comment: Same for `value` field that can be `int`, `str`, or any comparable object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to add an annotation to the `self` argument. For example:

```
T = TypeVar('T')
V = TypeVar('V', bound='BaseNode')

@dataclasses.dataclass
class BaseNode(Generic[T]):
    value: T
    parent: Optional[BaseNode[T]] = None
    left: Optional[BaseNode[T]] = None
    right: Optional[BaseNode[T]] = None

    @property
    def dummy(self: V) -> V:
        return self

    @property
    def dummy_parent(self: V) -> V:
        assert isinstance(self.parent, type(self))
        return self.parent
```

By the way, you should add the type argument to the optional properties so they don't become `BaseNode[Any]`, losing the benefit of generics!

Comment: it stop working when try return property `def dummy(self: V) -> V: return self.parent` instead of self, looks some incompatibility there

Comment: That really should be its own question, but see my edited answer. The issue is that `BaseNode.parent` wasn't specified to need to be the exact same type as the `BaseNode` it belongs to (consider subclassing).

Comment: yeah it solves issue I described, anyway I see inconsistencies with Node parent, left, right attributes usage, adding `assert isinstance(self.parent, type(self))` looks a bit hacky, `parent: Optional[V] = None` looks also interesting, but bring `test.py:17: error: Type variable "test.GenericNode" is unbound` issue